# Forcing a message loop to yield

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, ada

I hope this question isn't too broad.

I'm working with a legacy Ada application. This application is built around a very old piece of middleware that handles, among other things, our IPC. For the sake of this question, I can boil the middleware's provisions down to

1: a message loop that processes messages (from other programs or this program)

2: a function to send messages to this program or others

3: a function to read from a database

The program operates mainly on a message loop - simply something like

```
 loop
    This_Msg := Message_Loop.Wait_For_Message; -- Blocking wait call
    -- Do things based on This_Msg's ID
 end loop
```

however there are also callbacks that can be triggered by external stimuli. These callbacks run in their own threads. Some of these callbacks call the database-reading function, which has always been fine, EXCEPT, as we recently discovered, in a relatively rare condition. When this condition occurs, it turns out it isn't safe to read from the database when the message loop is executing its blocking Wait_For_Message.

It seemed like a simple solution would be to use a protected object to synchronize the Wait_For_Message and database read: if we try to read the database while Wait_For_Message is blocking, the read will block until Wait_For_Message returns, at which point the Wait_For_Message call will be blocked until the database read is complete. The next problem is that I can't guarantee the message loop will receive a message in a timely fashion, meaning that the database read could be blocked for an arbitrary amount of time. It seems like the solution to this is also simple: send a do-nothing message to the loop before blocking, ensuring that the Wait_For_Message call will yield.

What I'm trying to wrap my head around is:

If I send the do-nothing message and THEN block before the database read, I don't think I can guarantee that Wait_For_Message won't have returned, yielded, processed the do-nothing message, and started blocking again before the pre-database read block. I think I conceptually need to start blocking and THEN push a message, but I'm not sure how to do this. I think I could handle it with a second layer of locks, but I can't think of the most efficient way to do so, and don't know if that's even the right solution. This is really my first foray into concurrency in Ada, so I'm hoping for a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: You could look into [requeuing](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-9.html#2) on the PO. I tried working out an example, but it’s late (and I’m not at all sure that priorities actually work on macOS/FSF GCC).

Comment: I haven't read carefully enough, but still, is there control of the shared resource that somehow manages to block both `Wait_For_Message` and the database reads? Another shot from the hip: could you put timed/conditional entry call to use?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use a task for this; the following would have the task waiting at the `SELECT` to either process a message or access the DB while another call on an entry during the processing would queue on that entry for the loop to reiterate the `select`, thus eliminating the problem altogether... unless, somehow, your DB-access calls the message entry; but that shouldn't happen.

```Ada
Package Example is
    Task Message_Processor is
        Entry Message( Text : String );
        Entry Read_DB( Data : DB_Rec );
    End Message_Processor;
End Example;


Package Body Example is
    Task Body Message_Processor is
        Package Message_Holder is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders
          (Element_Type => String);
        Package DB_Rec_Holder is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders
          (Element_Type => DB_Rec);

        Current_Message : Message_Holder.Holder;
        Current_DB_Rec  : DB_Rec_Holder.Holder;
    Begin
        MESSAGE_LOOP:
        loop
            select
                accept Message (Text : in String) do
                    Current_Message:= Message_Holder.To_Holder( Text );
                end Message;
                -- Process the message **outside** the rendevouz.
                delay 1.0; -- simulate processing.
                Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( Current_Message.Element );
            or
                accept Read_DB (Data : in DB_Rec) do
                    Current_DB_Rec:= DB_Rec_Holder.To_Holder( Data );
                end Message;
                -- Process the DB-record here, **outside** the rendevouz.
            or
                Terminate;
            end select;
        end loop MESSAGE_LOOP;
    End Message_Processor;
End Example;
```